# Spring doesn't resolve classpath: in the file declaration in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, classpath, saml-2.0

I have the problem with resolve spring's "classpath:" feature. I a have my file in the next path:

```
src/main/java/resources/FederationMetadata.xml
```

Also, I have a bean:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

So my problem is that application fails with the next exception:

```
D:\myFolder\myProject\classpath:FederationMetadata.xml does not exist
```

As I understand Spring doesn't resolve file location. I tried with classpath*:, and it didn't help. In another project I have the same settings (with "classpath:") and it works fine. What it can be?

Comment: Are you starting the application from your IDE - e.g. Eclipse, or first compiling with Maven and then deploying? Can you post complete content of your WAR archive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was driving me crazy as well.

At some point I realized that `FilesystemMetadataProvider` was replaced with `ResourceBackedMetadataProvider`.

So now if you have your Metadata XML inside of the classpath, do something like this:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                        <constructor-arg value="/FederationMetadata.xml"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<value type="java.io.File">file:///FederationMetadata.xml</value>
```

instead of

```
<value type="java.io.File">classpath:FederationMetadata.xml</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it accessed from class path you need to put it inside 
WEB-INF/classes folder. 
the path is relative to classes folder ie if the file is inside

```
WEB-INF/classes/configs/somefile.xml
```

then

```
classpath:configs/somefile.xml
```